# record load test of desktop app with load runner running on cloud

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, windows, loadrunner

We have a windows app running on AWS. We access the app via remote desktop connection.

This app has the ability to serve 50 concurrent users. Now I have to launch loadtest to verify if its able to serve 50 concurrent user or not.

How can I record test with loadrunner for that app which is running on cloud? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to test the app infrastructure or the remote desktop infrastructure of AWS?  These are two different questions.

What do you know about the architecture of this application, the next upstream architectural component that it communicates with, the communication method, etc...?   You will need to understand this if you want to scrape away the interface and test at the application layer protocol or developer API layer.   Barring this you either go to the source and use Visual Studio or go up a tier to use Remote Desktop, a protocol supported by LoadRunner

Comment: Thanks you very much for your reply James.

Comment: I am intended to test apps infrastructure. Mainly need to generate load on server calls/api's. As its installed on a cloud server I am not aware how to trace the server call. I could have used some network sniffing tool to read the server call if it was installed on local machine, but dont know how to trace server calls of a cloud server (where the app is installed). 
As I could not trace the server call so not aware of communication protocol.
 I already email to our vendor for those architecture level detail, didn't here from then yet. once I know it I will share those here.

Comment: What my understanding is I cloud have learn the communication protocol of this app by myself if I was able to trace the network call. but still straggling to find out a better way to do it.

Comment: What does the application architecture suggest is the next upstream component and therefore what protocols may be in play?  Once you understand the communications architecture then you can head to the LoadRunner manuals for that particular protocol for guidance on how recording (or non-recorded development using templates) will work.   Otherwise you have few options: Winsock (not desirable), GUI (slightly less desirable), Citrix or RDP (Windows Terminal Server) virtual users.   If you have access to the source code then you can consider a Visual Studio Template Virtual User